# How to cache the queryset in django

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have three models.

```
class ManagerOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    kam = models.ForeignKey(KeyAccountManager, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


    @property
    def quantity(self):
        return OrderData.objects.filter(order_id = self.order.id) \
                .aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']


class Order(models.Model):
order_data = models.ManyToManyField('anotherapp', through='OrderData', related_name='+')

class OrderData(models.Model):
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

now i am trying to get the total quantity for each order.but it's calling the OrderData model again and again (N+1 problem). I read about prefetch_related and i put the same in my view.

```
 queryset = models.KeyAccountManagerOrder.objects.all().prefetch_related('order__order_data')
```

but still it's calling the OrderData model again and again.